# Ubuntu 20.04.3 server installer does not see m.2 ssd

Tags: server, system-installation, ssd

Trying to install Ubuntu server on my old laptop however it is not showing my ssd as an option. The drive is visible in the bios and my first attempt the iso was on the drive itself and still wouldn't show it. The drive was freshly formatted before I took it out of my main computer.

The laptop in question is an Asus rog gl552v and the ssd is a samsung ssd 850 evo m.2 500gb
intel i7 6700hq
nvidia gtx 960m

Comment: Will the notebook run *only* Ubuntu Server, or will you be doing this as a multi-boot system?

Comment: Yes just Ubuntu Server. I've done fdisk -l and the drive shows up there.

Comment: boot to live and run lsblk, is it showing up there? Is the m.2 running on a sata interface or is it running on a pcie interface?